# Objects and Instances in Kotlin

Tags: class, object, kotlin, instance

Can anybody explain how variable "***a***" gets to be given a ***type*** of a *class name* "**A**" and not the traditional "***primitive*** ***types***"?

for example:

```
Class A (var: string) {

}

Class B {
var a : A = A ("string")

}

fun main (args: Array<String>){
var b = B ()
prinln(b.a)

}
```

The goal here is to give the instance of "***Class B***" the properties of "***Class A***". I need to understand why it has to be done this way, and how does a "***class***" gets to be *acting* as a variable "***type***".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not a valid Kotlin code. It has syntax errors. The following is the correct version:

```
class A (var string: String) {

}

class B {
    var a : A = A ("string")

}

fun main (args: Array<String>){
    var b = B ()
    println(b.a)

}
```

Here is the explanation:

- The class keyword starts with lowercase `c` as `class` not `Class`.
- The arguments require the identifier and then type: `var param: String`
- The print method is misspelled. It is `println` not `prinln`.

**Regarding your question:**

> In Java, we have two types of type—primitive (e.g. int, long, boolean,
>   byte, char, etc.) and reference types (e.g. array, String). Java uses
>   wrappers (like java.lang.Integer) to make primitive types behave like
>   objects. But in Kotlin, there is no such distinction. Instead, all
>   types are objects.

More here: [Kotlin From Scratch: Variables, Basic Types, and Arrays](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/kotlin-from-scratch-variables-basic-types-arrays-type-inference-and-comments--cms-29328)

You can define your own objects using class. Here is a complete reference to understand: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

In class B you are instantiating class A and assign it to a variable `a`. In this case, the variable `a` is a member/ property of class B.

Answer (score 0):

There are no primitive types in Kotlin (only in Java); every type derives from nullable object type `Any?`. Class B receives the fields and methods of class A via the common OO mechanism of [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).